# ThreeJS Group RayCast

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, raycasting

How do we raycast on group of mesh? Whenever I do it on a group of mesh the intersects list object shows null or undefined. I also tried doing intersects[0].object.parent but no luck.

Comment: Mark as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580283/can-a-three-js-raycaster-intersect-a-group